# Get the state of a multiple select with jquery

Tags: jquery, select, cross-browser, show-hide

Hoping you guys can help me with a little problem I'm having

**Desired functionality:**
I am trying to make a cross browser collapsible multiple selection box, that only shows the selected options when the box is collapsed (collapsed when mouse exits the select) and then restores them all when the box is expanded (mouse over) and retains the state of the checked items. See the Fiddle at the bottom for the desired functionality (Firefox only)

**Problem:**
The problem is that the checked state doesn't seem to be recorded in the HTML, is it maybe in the form GET/POST data, if so how to access that. Either that or I am missing something or doing something wrong, a highly probable reason for it not working ;-)

**Help needed:** Is there a way to restore a multiple select's options with their previously selected(checked) states?

[jsFiddle jQuery collapsible select box](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/wvs8g4c6/2/)

```
function removeOptions($select) {
    var $optionsToRemove = $select.find('option:not(:selected)'); //filter for non selected options
    $optionsToRemove.remove(); //remove
}
function setSelectCurrentState($select) {
        $select.data("currentHTML", $select.html()); //save the current state (this does not work for multiple)
}
function restoreOptions($select) {
    var ocHTML = $select.data("currentHTML"); //retrieve the data
    if (ocHTML != undefined) {
        $select.html(ocHTML); //restore (the state is not sotred in the html so this doesn't work)
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var $hoverSelect = $('#hoverSelect');

    /*As we leave the select box store the current state and then remove filtered options*/
    $hoverSelect.mouseleave(function () {
        setSelectCurrentState($hoverSelect); // save the current state
        removeOptions($hoverSelect); //remove options
    });

    /*When we hover back over the select restore all options with their selected states*/
    $hoverSelect.mouseenter(function () {
        restoreOptions($hoverSelect);
    });

});
```

*If you recognise your code in this fiddle sorry for not crediting you but I lost the link.*

I also have a fiddle for something similar that uses just CSS and works fine in Firefox, but as IE and Edge don't allow the setting of option *display:none;* it does not work in these browsers. This code will give an example of how I would like it to work if you use Firefox to view it.

[jsFiddle CSS collapsible select box](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/Lgr8nuoj/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic state of input elements is not included in `.html()`, that just contains the HTML from the DOM.

Instead of saving the HTML, save the option elements themselves. Their state will be included in this.

```js
function removeOptions($select) {
  var $optionsToRemove = $select.find('option:not(:selected)'); //filter for non selected options
  $optionsToRemove.remove(); //remove
}

function setSelectCurrentState($select) {
  $select.data("currentOptions", $select.find('option'));
}

function restoreOptions($select) {
  var oldOptions = $select.data("currentOptions"); //retrieve the data
  if (oldOptions) {
    $select.empty().append(oldOptions);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hoverSelect = $('#hoverSelect');

  /*As we leave the select box store the current state and then remove filtered options*/
  $hoverSelect.mouseleave(function() {
    setSelectCurrentState($hoverSelect); // save the current state
    removeOptions($hoverSelect); //remove options
  });

  /*When we hover back over the select restore all options with their selected states*/
  $hoverSelect.mouseenter(function() {
    restoreOptions($hoverSelect);
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #99b;
}
form {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
#hoverSelect {
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#hoverSelect:hover {
  height: 150px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Collapsable select box</h1>
<h2>only shows selected items when collapsed, all when expanded (hover)</h2>
<br />
<div id="wrapper">
  <form>
    <select id="hoverSelect" name="hoverSelect" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2" class="two">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
      <option value="6">Six</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<br />
<h2>It should remember state but doesn't</h2>
```